# pcl::ConcaveHull<pointXYZRGB> reconstruct returns a point cloud with all RGB values as black

Tags: point-cloud-library, qhull

When I run pcl::concaveHull reconstruct using PointXYZRGB with the RGB values previously defined from scene color values, the returned cloud has RGB values that are zeros or black.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask);  if you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem;  also, remember to include a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve);  people will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

use ConcaveHull.setKeepInformation(true)